# App error on real phone

Tags: android

I test my app on my phone
it work normally on AVD
but it cant work on my phone

Here is the error log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method goto MainActivity(View) in the activity class com.FF_studio.device_flash_1.EulaActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'agree'
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4469)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18788)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: goto MainActivity [class android.view.View]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:864)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3834)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: `goTo`? That's not a Java method. Please include your code

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your error logs it looks like you are trying to access one activity reference from another activity. Since you are not doing this using standard intent mechanism in android, it may be possible that the existing activity might be destroyed by the system (due to low memory, or do not keep activity setting set to on in developer option), as a result the reference to the activity is lost and you are getting this exception.

Your code will work intermittently and shows different behaviour based on the system available resources and user interaction with the app.
Ideally you consider re looking at your code and should not access one activity directly from another activity.

Comment: Actually, the error looks like a method was called that doesn't based on `NoSuchMethodException`

Comment: But since it is working in emulator, it means that the code is getting compiled, and i assumed that he may have defined a custom method with name goTo to handle the use case.

Comment: I run this app on AVD by "run as"    but just copying the apk from the Bin file to my phone .